# Why no vowels for the sounds of the shofar?

Tags: prayer-book, writing-printing, vowels-nekudot, shofar

In three different machzorim (a Rinat Yisrael, an Artscroll and a Koren -- the ones I had access to over the holiday) the listings of the sounds of the shofar are printed without any vowels. [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz%2C_Sounding_of_the_Shofar?lang=en) does the same thing. Is there a particular source/reason why one should not list them with vowels, or is it an old printer's whim that became standardized because no one thought to ask why? The only suggestion I got was that, if you look in the all-Hebrew Artscroll siddur, the short instructions before certain prayers are similarly without vowels, so the sounds, not read by the individual, are similar "directions." However, the Kabbalistic names of Hashem are also printed without vowels so I don't know if the lack is to turn the words into instructions, or something forbidden to be pronounced.

Comment: I think your hunch is correct. It seems that "instructional words" don't get vowels. That's not unique to Art Scroll, BTW. Perhaps, this is to prevent a less knowledgeable reader from thinking that it is a prayer and he should verbalize these words as he would the other prayers.